# How to get the value of an Array Index Within a Dictionary to Populate the Tableview

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, dictionary, uisearchbar

I have product tags stored in the the following variable:

```
var productTags : [String : [String]] = [:]
```

I also have a search bar for my tableView where I populate the following variable based on what the user is searching for from the productTags:

```
var searchResults: [String : [String]] = [:]
```

So the content of the these two variables would be something like this:

```
productTags = [ product1 : [tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4],
                product2 : [tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4, tag 5], 
                product3 : [tag1, tag2, tag3]
              ] 
// similar for the searchResults depending on the search
```

Now I'd like to populate only the `tag1` of each product into the tableView. How do I go about doing this?

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return //what should I be returning here? 
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Identifiers.HomeSearchCell, for: indexPath) as! HomeSearchCell

    cell.productName?.text = //how can I populate the "tag1" of the product in here? so the label shows the tag1 as the search result

    return cell
}
```

I also want to make sure I can track which tag specifically the user is clicking on so I can track back the tag to the product ID. For example, if you search `tag1` of `product2` and then you see `tag1` in the search result in the table view and click on it; how can I get the product ID which in this case is `product2` from the row you selected on?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
// what should I put here to get the productID of the tag/row selected by the user from the searchresults? 
    }
```

**EDIT:** 
This is how I populate my `productTags`:

```
db.collection(DatabaseRef.searchTags).document(DatabaseRef.productTags).getDocument { snapshot, error in

            guard error == nil, let snapshot = snapshot else {
                return
            }

            let data = snapshot.data()!

            for (key, _) in data {

                let productTags = data["\(key)"] as? [Any]

                if let maxIndex = productTags?.count {

                    for index in 0..<maxIndex {
                        if let tag = productTags![index] as? String, tag != "" {

                            if self.productTags[key] == nil {
                                self.productTags[key] = []
                                self.productTags[key]?.append(tag)
                            } else {
                                self.productTags[key]?.append(tag)
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

and this is how I filter my `productTags` to populate the `searchResults`:

```
searchResults = productTags.filter({ (productTags) -> Bool in
            if let name = productTags.value as? [String] {
                for tag in name {
                    let isMatch = tag.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(SearchText)
                    return isMatch
                }
            }
            return false
        })
```

Comment: I'm confused. "If you search tag1 of product2" -- this will result in just one single value, or am I missing somthing? So why would you use a table for this? If you search for "tag1" in _any_ product, would the table then display three rows, each with a "tag1" value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TableViews work best when dealing with Arrays. If possible, I would turn the dictionary into an array of `Dictionary<String:[String]>`. So it would look something like this.

```
var productTags: [[String: [String]]] = [
    [product1: [tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4]],
    [product2 : [tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4, tag5]],
    [product3 : [tag1, tag2, tag3]]
]
```

Then from there you can return the number of product dictionaries in the array

```
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: 
        Int) -> Int {

         return productTags.count 
    }
```

And from there you can access the productTagDictionaries by indexPath.row

```
 let productTags = productTags[indexPath.row].values.first
 cell.productName?.text = productTags?.first
```

Comment: **NOTE** - In addition to this, because you are using arrays, you will get order safety. Dictionaries are unordered.